# Proving the triangle inequality property of a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have to show that $d(x,y) = \sqrt{|y-x|}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric. The first two properties were fairly trivial, however I'm having issues showing that $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. I tried this approach: $d(x,z) = \sqrt{|z-x|}  = \sqrt{|z-y+y-x|} \leq \sqrt{|z-y| + |y-x|}$, but it doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $a,b\ge0$

$$\sqrt{a+b}\le\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$
as squaring  each side we get
$$
a+b\le a+b+2\sqrt{ab}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that should do it! I'm sort of surprised that for some reason I was never taught that trick in my mathematical education until now.